# Restrict Chrome Omnibox Extension to My Suggestions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, omnibox

I'm having a little problem that's I've seen on other technical-based sites, although maybe my problem is just a little bit more specific. I'm writing an extension for Google Chrome that uses an omnibox to make suggestions. It works just fine, and I am able to make suggestions once the keyword is entered and the tab is hit.

However, I want to restrict the browser's suggests to **ONLY** the ones that I have listed and built into my extension. I want to exclude the suggestions Chrome might add based on the browser's favorites, history, etc. This is mostly because the extension is being changed often as the links it leads to change often, and I want to remove old suggestions from the browser that the user may have used last week or so.

Say I have this:

```
var suggestions = [];
suggestions.push({
    content : "runExtension=" + text,
    description : "Run Extension: " + text
});
suggestions.push({
    content : "debugJS=" + text,
    description : "Debug JavaScript: " + text
});
```

I want ONLY those two things to be listed in Chrome. It would also be helpful if I can order the suggestions, but I'll take what I can get. Has anyone come across this?

Comment: Tried wiping the history via the [`chrome.history`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history) API?

Comment: @Xan It depends. If the URLs are no longer valid (as stated in the question), then removing those history items is not going to cause harm.

Answer (score 1):

At most you can call `chrome.omnibox.setDefaultSuggestion` to push one of your suggestions to the top.

You can't control other entries in the menu, nor, to my knowledge, reorder them.